# Merge multiple arrays without overwriting first found value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge a set of arrays coming from different objects. Lets say I have a setup like this:

```
class Base {
    static $defaults = array (
        'time'   => 'DEFAULT',
        'color'  => 'DEFAULT',
        'friend' => 'DEFAULT',
        'pub'    => 'DEFAULT',
        'money'  => 'DEFAULT',
    );
    static function isDefault ( $key, $value ) {}
    $properties;
}
class A extends Base {
    function __construct() {
        $data = array( 'time' => '6pm', 'friend' => 'Jack' );
        $this->properties = array_merge( self::$defaults, $data );
    };
class B extends Base {
    function __construct() {
        $data = array( 'pub' => 'The Lion', 'friend' => 'Jane' );
        $this->properties = array_merge( self::$defaults, $data );
    };
}
class C extends Base {
    function __construct() {
        $data = array( 'money' => 'none', 'pub' => 'Queens' );
        $this->properties = array_merge( self::$defaults, $data );
    };
}
$sequence = array( new A, new B, new C );
```

All I know is that the objects are in sequence and an array called `properties` exists. I want to merge these arrays so that the result looks like:

```
array (
    'time'   => '6pm',
    'color'  => 'DEFAULT',
    'friend' => 'Jack',
    'pub'    => 'The Lion',
    'money'  => 'none',
)
```

I want the first none default value to be stored. What would be a fast method of doing this?

Comment: What's the sense in controlling your settings in such weird way? Why do you want new instantiation to change entire context? It's hard to comprehend (even for your short sample code it required some minutes for me to realize what's going on)

Comment: @AlmaDo It's part of a plugin system where the container needs to know valid callbacks within its contained group. Rather than calling on each instance I'd like to build the array once on initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Define isDefault

```
static function isDefault ( $key, $value ) {
    return($value == self::$defaults[$key]);
}
```

Step 2: Loop.

```
<?php
$result = array();
foreach($sequence AS $object){
    foreach($object->properties AS $key=>$value){
        if(!isset($result[$key]) || Base::isDefault($key, $result[$key])){
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/anh-hrc

Result was:

```
array(5) {
  ["time"]=>  string(3) "6pm"
  ["color"]=>  string(7) "DEFAULT"
  ["friend"]=>  string(4) "Jack"
  ["pub"]=>  string(8) "The Lion"
  ["money"]=>  string(4) "none"
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :) Was a neat challenge.